# How To make regex for filtering file type and part of filename

Tags: regex

My base string is

```
http://xx.com/3-115_high.mp4
```

I'm trying to figure out what the regular expression that would give the following:

1. `true` if ends in `.mp4` (I think it is `/(.(mp4))$/` )
2. `true` if ends in `.mp4` and also includes the string "_high" preferably before the `.`, but could be anyplace as an other option if before the `.` is too hard.

Comment: True when ends in `.mp4` covers case2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly `/\.mp4$/` will work for both cases, but if you need more specific one you can try that: `/(_high)?\.mp4$/` or `/_high\.mp4$/` if _high is **required**.

Answer (score 0):

Not so difficult:

1. `/\.mp4$/`
2. (`_high` anywhere): `/_high.*\.mp4$/`
3. (`_high` right before the dot): `/_high\.mp4$/`

Comment: Re `2.` >> anywhere in url path, not filename (e.g. `http://xx.com/m_high/189/d02.mp4`)

Answer (score 0):

1. True, if the filename ends with `.mp4`

   ```
   Regex.IsMatch(url, @"[.]mp4$")
   ```
2. True, if the filename ends with `_high.mp4`

   ```
   Regex.IsMatch(url, @"_high[.]mp4$")
   ```
3. True, if the filename ends with `.mp4` and the filename includes the string `_high`

   ```
   Regex.IsMatch(url, @"_high[^/]*[.]mp4$")
   ```
4. True, if the filename ends with `.mp4` and the url includes the string `_high`

   ```
   Regex.IsMatch(url, @"_high.*[.]mp4$")
   ```